# Law of total probability

Tags: probability

$$\begin{align}
p_{ij}(k, k+n) =& \Pr\left\{X_{k+n}=j\mid X_k=i\right\}\\
=& \sum_{r=1}^R \Pr\left\{X_{k+n}=j\mid X_u=r\color{red}, X_k=i\right\}\Pr\left\{X_u=r\mid X_k=i\right\}
\end{align}$$

Markov Chains; Using the law of total probability, one can obtain the following equation. I am not entirely sure how it can be obtained. Does the comma between $X_u$ and $X_k$ means intersection between them? $X_u$ is supposed to be a partition of the sample space I think. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $X_u$ is presumably supposed to be a random variable.

Answer (score 1):

The comma should mean intersection, as you have guessed.

Remember from the definition of conditional probability,

$$\begin{align}
\Pr\left[X_{k+n}=j\mid X_k=i\right]
=& \frac{\Pr[X_{k+n}=j, X_k=i]}{\Pr[X_k=i]}\\
=& \frac{\sum_r\Pr[X_{k+n}=j, X_k=i, X_u=r]}{\Pr[X_k=i]}\\
=& \sum_r\frac{\Pr[X_{k+n}=j\mid X_k=i, X_u=r]\Pr[X_k=i, X_u=r]}{\Pr[X_k=i]}\\
=& \sum_r\Pr[X_{k+n}=j\mid X_k=i, X_u=r]\Pr[X_u=r\mid X_k=i]
\end{align}$$

where the summation is over all possible value of $X_u$.

Comment: Splendid job Peterwhy. The comma does mean intersection as the values of X(u) are summed. Thanks a bunch.